# Steam Game not Validated

Tags: steam, technical-issues

Recently I have encountered an issue with steam. If you turn off your computer too fast, steam will register a game you were running as uninstalled. In my case it is GTA V. I have looked far and wide but only found that I should start installing and then steam will recognise the previous files. The problem is, I don't have enough space to start the download to be able to register it. I have slow internet and don't want to wait 5-7 hours to reinstall the game.

Comment: Have you tried [checking your installed files](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2037-QEUH-3335)? It should be much faster (more like 5 minutes instead of hours).

Comment: The game appears as uninstalled, so checking the integrity isn't possible. It's on my drive just steam doesn't recognise it.

Comment: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/315449/steam-says-game-is-suddenly-uninstalled-i-know-it-is-not   seems to be the samy question with another game... maybe the presented solutions will work in your case too? -- Other than that I got no idea, sry, hope you get it fixed...

Comment: Thanks, I got it fixed using the app manifest. Turned out it had somehow got cleared, so I replaced it and its working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is encountering the same problem with a different game, find the app manifest and replace it with the one in steamapps. The app manifest tells steam what an installed game is, so if you still have the game files you can replace the manifest if you dont have enough space. If you do have enough space then you can just discover the files by hitting install and steam will do the rest.